# docker-machine behind corporate proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, centos-6, docker

I've installed Machine (Docker tool), and I'm trying to learn how to use it by following the user guide. I'm running centOS 6.6

As I am working behind a company proxy, I exported some environnement variables to get things to work :

```
#!/bin/bash

http_proxy='http://<domain>\\<login>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>'
https_proxy='https://<domain>\\<login>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>'
export http_proxy https_proxy
```

My problem comes out when I want to create a machine. For example, I'm testing it using VirtualBox (which I also installed) :

```
sudo -E docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev
```

I use the -E option to keep sudo from discarding the environment variables. I assume the problem is not coming from the 2 proxy lines, because I have been using them in some other cases and it was working (example : downloading an image from Docker hub, downloading files with cURL, installing pip packages, ...).

Output of that command line :

```
WARN[0005] Unable to check for the latest release: Get https://api.github.com/repos/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases: dial tcp 192.30.252.136:443: i/o timeout
INFO[0005] Downloading boot2docker.iso to /root/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso...
ERRO[0005] Error creating machine: Get : unsupported protocol scheme ""
WARN[0005] You will want to check the provider to make sure the machine and associated resources were properly removed.
FATA[0005] Error creating machine
```

Apparently other people have encoutered some similar problem, and it seems it has been solved : https://github.com/docker/machine/pull/625

I might be doing something wrong, but I really don't get it, and can't find a lot of help via google search.

Comment: this should fix your issue: https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/8f82b762749bb8dcf52c6dd0774b927510c5e885/docs/reference/create.md